# Serializing HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a service that allows real-time concurrent modification of canvases by more than 2 users. I have been exploring the literature behind the best ways of doing this and have not found a lot to go of off.

So far I have found methods which serialize the canvas using the `canvas.toDataUrl()`. The issue here is that it seems rather inefficient to redraw the entire canvas when only very few pixels have changed (that is, when another user modifies it).

I do not really know where to start with this particular project and would love some help with that.

No more than 40 users would be looking at the canvas at once.

Comment: Why not only send the diff from each user? If I only change 3 pixels, just broadcast which 3 pixels and what I did to them.

Comment: That was my gut instinct. The issue here is that I am not sure if that is a good solution. I could be neglecting something about an implementation like that. I have not read or heard of anybody doing something like that.

Comment: What kind of modifications are being done?

Comment: The application simulates a blackboard and it is used by teachers to teach students remotely. It also allows students to write on the BB when allowed.

Comment: I see...a user will be dragging to create lines on the board, so each single user modification is a single batch of moveTo and multiple lineTo's.  You could capture the moveTo/lineTo points from a users drag. Then serialize that drag into one JSON object like this: {path:"M100,100, L150,100, 200,200"} where M means moveTo and L is a series of lineTo points.  Then send that to the server via websockets (fallback to polling).  Then the server can broadcast that JSON object to all users.  Last, javascript on each client draws the moveTo and LineTo's in the received object. (Timestamps required)

Comment: @markE, yes, I believe that a method along those lines will have to be  the way of doing it. You guys have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what and how users are drawing.

1. If they can draw/manipulate only predefined set of primitives, like software block chart then you can send just list of JSON serialized data describing those primitives and their location.
2. If drawing is just a pixel bitmap like this http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/ then you can do drawing into bitmap and broadcasting that bitmap serialized as PNG on mouseup or so.
3. To publish this to all users I would do something socket.io based. Node.js for example has a lot of samples of how to do socket.io based chats. Chat is conceptually pretty close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: c-smile, my app is very similar to 2 so far. I initially thought about parsing the canvas as a bitmap but found no literature on it. 

For the prototype of this project I am using Firebase for real-time data sharing. The real project will either use Express + Socket.io or Scala with Play 2.0 and Akka.

Comment: Also, if I broadcast the bitmap at every little change, this is going to be particularly resource intensive. Like it was suggested above, I could only broadcast changes to the bitmap itself (that seems complicated to sync with many users).

Comment: Do you know a way to check for changes in a canvas? That way I only broadcast the changes?

Comment: @Alexander Ventura: on mousedown I would create bitmap with graphics, on mouseup will package that bitmap as PNG and send it. PNG is quite effective in compressing almost empty bitmaps. I'd suggest to try this first and then if you will see problems optimize it further.

Comment: I am currently working in that, its actually not bad at all. It is much faster than I expected.